# kafka muliple topic seggregation in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am reading from kafka as lines from 2 different files in 2 different topics.   Example of lines :

ex: 
File1: `2015-04-15T18:44:14+01:00,192.168.11.42,%ASA-2-106007:`
File2: `"04/15/2012","18:44:14",,"Start","Unknown","Unknown",,"192.168.63.128","444","2","7","192.168.63.128",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

I am able to read from spark from two different topics.Code is like below:

```
SparkConf sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreaming").setMaster("local[5]");
        JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfig,Durations.seconds(5));
        final HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(jsc.sc());
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jsc, 
                                                                                        prop.getProperty("zookeeper.connect"),
                                                                                        prop.getProperty("group.id"), 
                                                                                        topicMap
                                                                                        );

        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                        return tuple2._2();
                    }
                });
```

The problem i see now is :

**lines** rdd contains both the line which is obvious.How do I segregate or find out which records is from which topic or which file.
**The reason behind this is I want to apply different logic for different topic which is coming in spark. But rdd has all the row at time**

Appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a `createDirectStream` overloaded method which accepts `scala.Function1<kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata<K,V>,R> messageHandler` as parameter. Than, you just need to pass as `messageHandler` a function which - getting a `MessageAndMetadata` object as input - returns the actual message and the topic.

Here I post to you the code to do that written in Scala. You can easily adapt it in Java:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String,String)](ssc, 
        kafkaParams, 
        topicOffsetsMap, 
        (m:MessageAndMetadata[String, String])=> (m.topic,m.message()) 
        )
```